# How do I make a service provider or trait to integrate Algolia in my Laravel's controllers?

Tags: laravel, traits, algolia, service-provider

I am using [Algolia search client PHP for Laravel](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php) 
and I want to use it without Laravel Scout.

Right now I have to do this in every controller where I need to use Algolia:

```
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('xxx', 'xxx');

$index = $client->initIndex('index');

$index->doSomeAlgoliaFunction();
```

How can I turn this into a service provider so I don't have to init Algolia each time I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to bind it to the container. In your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, in the `register` method:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use AlgoliaSearch\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Client::class, function () {
            return new Client('xxx', 'xxx');
        });
    }
}
```

Then if you need it in the controller for instance, you can have typehint it on the constructor and Laravel will automatically pass the instance of the client.

```
use AlgoliaSearch\Client;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $client;

    public function __contruct(Client $client)
    {
       $this->client = $client;
    }

}
```

If you need it elsewhere, you can use the `app()` helper function to get it from the container.

```
use AlgoliaSearch\Client;

class Something
{

    public function doMagic()
    {
        $algoliaIndex = app(Client::class)->initIndex('my_index_name');

        $algoliaIndex->addObject(....);
    }

}
```

**NOTE** get the credentials from `config()` or `env()`, avoid committing your ADMIN api key.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your base Controller

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    protected $client;
    public function __contruct(){
       $this->client =  new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('xxx', 'xxx');
    }

}
```

Now you can use in your Controllers

```
$index = $this->client->initIndex('index');

$index->doSomeAlgoliaFunction();
```

Hope this helps.